# Time format with a plus sign?

Tags: csv, dolphindb, timestamp-with-timezone

My sample data is in the format of "2020-01-01 00:00:00+08:00" and the number after "+" represents the time zone. When I import the csv file to the database, there is no match time format. How could I fill in the time format in dolphindb?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the csvFile contains the following data:

```py
time
2020-01-01 00:00:00+08:00
2020-02-01 00:00:00+08:00
2020-03-01 10:00:00+08:00
```

To load the data:

```py
csvFile="D:/DolphinDB/timezone1.csv"
schemaTB = extractTextSchema(csvFile)
update schemaTB set type="STRING" where name="time"
t = loadText(csvFile,,schemaTB)
t.replaceColumn!(`time,datetimeParse(left(t.time,19),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

The above scripts load the data in STRING type and then convert them to the DATETIME type.